# Vertical scroll-bar in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display a vertical scroll-bar in alert dialog may be fast. Because it contails thousands of data to display.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                PublishingPublisher.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select following:");
    //  builder.setFastScrollEnabled(true); // can i have like this something.
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to display the `listView` in `alertDialog` then scroll will be displayed:

```
builder.setView(<YourListView>);
```

Comment: I dont have any layout for it, i am creating it pragmatically like builder.setItems()

Comment: ok then set those items in a listview and add listview to builder

Answer (score 0):

Indeed! you have to make custom alert Dialog, which includes your listivew inside your dialog with your thousands of data,like below:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_row, null, false);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(customView);
```